# Get tiled bitmap / repeated bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a seamless background, and I have successfully show it on the screen repeatedly using below code:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
mBackground.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

However, I got an issue with getting the bitmap to save later. The background is matched screen size in width and height. When I try with below code to get the bitmap, the saved image is just the original seamless pattern.

```
((BitmapDrawable) mBackground.getBackground()).getBitmap()
```

I have no idea how to generate repeated background image.

Comment: you want to draw that `BitmapDrawable`?

Comment: Yes. I want to draw that bitmap repeatedly with different sizes.

Comment: if you want to draw it, then call `draw()` method on that `Drawable`

Comment: Can I set specific width and height?

Comment: not only width and height but even left, top, right and bottom

Comment: Can you give an example? The `draw()` method consume a `Canvas` object. You can post your answer below, if it worked I can accept it.

Comment: just read `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code may help:

```
    int width = 100;//initialise
    int height= 100;//initialise

    //you say "The background is matched screen size in the question"
    width  = mBackground.getWidth();//  get width  of screen
    height = mBackground.getHeight();// get height of screen

    //Create bitmap for canvas        
    Bitmap tiledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );//create a Bipmap for us to save later
    canvas = new Canvas( tiledBitmap );//associate bitmap to canvas

    bitmapDrawable.setBounds( 0, 0, width , height );//set bounds
    bitmapDrawable.draw( canvas );//draw tiled image to canvas ( and so Bitmap )

    //tiledBitmap now contains your tiled image
```